# How can I have a quicker output in this python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I want to display the time in the terminal/console, every second that passes I'd like the previous time deleted and replaced with the new time (which will be one second further). However, when I run my program it displays the time not after **every** second, but after **every two** seconds. My code looks kinda stupid, but I'm not aware if there's a way to modify it. Here's my code:

```
import time
import os

while True:
    print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    os.system('clear')
```

So for example if I execute this code at 08:12:33, this will be the result:
-First: **08:12:33**
-Screen is cleared
-Then: **08:12:35**
-Screen is cleared
-Then: **08:12:37**
-Screen is cleared
.
.
.

Any help, modification or hint will be greatly appreciated.

**EDITION:** *Firstly, thank you all guys for the variety of hints and answers. Since many of you say the code works fine on your consoles, I'd also like to add that I'm running this code on VS Code console. Although your codes have worked fine on your consoles, I haven't been able to reach the desired output. Is this possible that the problem is with my console? Maybe it can't track the speed?*

Comment: Note that `os.system('clear')` is by far the slowest thing in this code.

Comment: @Liana another question, are you on windows? and if so, which console are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Using an escape sequence (`\033[2J` for clear and `\033[H` for homing the cursor) to clear the screen would be faster than spawning a subprocess:

```
import time

while True:
    print('\033[2J\033[H'+time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    time.sleep(1)
```

or use libraries such as [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), [ansi](https://pypi.org/project/ansi/), etc... that should provide an abstraction over those raw escape sequences.

Comment: Taking this a step further, using the curses library would be an improvement. You don't have to learn control codes and behavior is device-independent.

Comment: This helped me have the seconds modify every one second, but yet the result somehow jumps two seconds forward every time. like if it's 38, then after a second it shows 40, but it needs to be 39.

Comment: @Liana remove the time delay

Comment: @okawo yet nothing changes.

Comment: @Liana you sure? `while 1: print('\033[2J\033[H'+time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))`  is not only not skipping seconds for me, its almost in sync with my system panel clock

Comment: Mine is also sync with it, but the problem is with the display. It does not display every second, but every two seconds.

Comment: try to print it without clearing the console or any delays, when you stop it check if its incrementing the time by 2 seconds between prints

Answer (score 1):

Use a scheduler

```
import os, sched, time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def print_time(s):
    s.enter(1, 1, print_time, (s,))
    os.system('clear')
    print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
                                             
s.enter(1, 1, print_time, (s,))
s.run()
```

Comment: the output does not change for me :(

Comment: what version of python are you using? Works fine for me on python 3.8

Comment: I'm using 3.8.5

Answer (score 0):

That's not what's happening- you're continuously and without stop printing the time (on my console this does show every change, but on yours it might not).You should sleep between prints so you don't miss anything.
Btw, time.ctime() is irrelevant. You're not using the return value.

Try this:

```
import time
import os

while True:
    print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    os.system('clear')
```

Comment: time.sleep(1) might be better since its only displaying seconds anyway

Comment: I guess, but the question is how close you want to be to the actual time- if you want your printed time to be as close as possible to the "real" second changing, then you want the lowest sleep possible (.3 is obviously arbitrary, but 1 is as far away as you can be- any more and you may miss second changes)

Comment: sadly I copy pasted what you just wrote and the result is the same... I can only see it every 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I used os.system('cls') which worked fine for me

```
import time
import os

time.ctime()
while True:
    print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    os.system('cls')
```

Comment: It's weird how I copy paste the same code to my IDE and yet the console gives me the same problem I explained... Maybe this is some problem not regarding to my code but to my console? Maybe mine can't keep track of it?

Comment: I think it might be your console then, since mine worked for me

Comment: I also believe the same. Thank you :')